# Comparing values within one JavaScript array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of objects like so:

```
[{ value: 40,
  username: 'Name 1',
  id: 'high'
},
{ value: 30,
  username: 'Name 2',
  id: 'low',
},
{ value: 60,
  username: 'Name 1',
  id: 'low',
},
{ value: 50,
  username: 'Name 2',
  id: 'high'
}]
```

I want to compare the objects with the same `username` key and return false where the object has the property `id: low` and its `value` is higher than any corresponding object with its `id` set to `high`.

So for this object **false** would be returned because the third object has the `low` for its id and it has a higher value than the corresponding object with the same username with `high` in its id.

Currently I'm filtering the array into two separate arrays like so.

```
    const higherTest = test.filter(item => item.id === 'high');
    const lowerTest = test.filter(item => item.id === 'low');
```

And then compare both using a nested for loop but this seems excessive and I am wondering if there is a cleaner way?

Comment: I like the two filter approach, maybe with an additional reduce on each to get the low value amongst the 'high' set and the high value amongst the 'low' set for subsequent comparison. And presumably grouped by username, if it's per user.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the output you're trying to achieve?

Comment: It would be helpful if you provide the output for the given array

Comment: btw. all uers names are different.

Comment: The output I am looking for is a boolean value. For the above array false would be returned.

Comment: can a username have more than one high or low value?

Comment: must all high value be accompanied by a low value for each user name?

Answer (score 1):

You could take a hash table for visited names and store the low and height value. If a pair is found check the values and return the result of the check.

This approach uses a short circuit and returns for the first found `low > high` condition.

```js
var data = [{ value: 40, username: 'Name 1', id: 'high' }, { value: 30, username: 'Name 2', id: 'low' }, { value: 60, username: 'Name 1', id: 'low' }, { value: 50, username: 'Name 2', id: 'high' }],
    result = !data.some((m => ({ value, username, id }) => {
        const user = m[username] = m[username] || {};
        user[id] = value;
        return 'high' in user && 'low' in user && user.low > user.high;
    })({}));

console.log(result);
```